# Jquery inArray return true for non-existent object

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement

Nominatim reverse send that:

```
{
"place_id":118873576,
"licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
"osm_type":"way",
"osm_id":71122987,
"lat":"48.86742742576341",
"lon":"2.334017224974853",
"display_name":"Rue des Petits Champs, Quartier du Palais Royal, Paris 1er Arrondissement, Paris, Île-de-France, France métropolitaine, 75001, France",
"address":{
"road":"Rue des Petits Champs",
"city_block":"Quartier du Palais Royal",
"neighbourhood":"Paris 1er Arrondissement",
"suburb":"Paris",
"city_district":"Paris",
"county":"Paris",
"state":"Île-de-France",
"region":"France métropolitaine",
"postcode":"75001",
"country":"France",
"country_code":"fr"},
"boundingbox":["48.8671374","48.8675112","2.3336619","2.3352462"]
}
```

If I want Neighbourhood only I do that :

```
if($.inArray("neighbourhood", address) !== -1){
                    console.log(' neighbourhood only ');
                    result = address.neighbourhood;
                }
```

Generally I need only city but neighbourhood display too (This last is used for capital and big city).

```
if($.inArray("city", response) !== 0){
                    console.log(' city only ';
                    result = address.city;
                }
```

My function ($.inArray) or the condition (!== -1) seems wrong because even the object doesn't exist the condition return true and consider the condition

With this array object and these two condition the console display:
neighbourhood only and city only (but 'city' doesn't exist)

this problem can be repeated with other key : suburb and town.
if two or more key object exist inside array object there are a conflict and nothing display (using the same condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.inArray` is for arrays, use `in` for objects

```
if("city" in adress){
    console.log(' city only ';
    result = address.city;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . where is the documentation ? I can't find it . 
Can I use multiple object in the condition "in" or must I separate them by "&&"
ex : if("city, town" in adress){
or : if("city" in adress && "town" in adress){

Comment: Documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in . To check several properties use `in` in combination with `||` or `&&`, so, `if("city" in adress && "town" in adress)` is ok